# Where the NOTICE or error messages?

Tags: postgresql, copy, plpgsql

No NOTICE neither error messages at

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION copy_to_csv(
  fname text,
  query text,
  header boolean DEFAULT true,
  quotedfields text[] DEFAULT NULL,
  usedate boolean DEFAULT true
) RETURNS text AS $f$
DECLARE
  aux text :='';
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'HELLO!!!!!';
  IF p_quotedfields IS NOT NULL THEN
    aux := ', FORCE_QUOTE('|| array_to_string(quote_ident(quotedfields),',') ||')';
  END IF;
  aux := format(
    'COPY (%L) TO (%L) WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER %L%s)',
    query,
    CASE WHEN usedate THEN fname|| now()::date::text ELSE fname END ||'.csv',
    header,
    aux
  );
  RAISE NOTICE 'HELLO2';
  EXECUTE aux;
  RAISE NOTICE 'HELLO3';
  RETURN aux;
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

... Calling with `select copy_to_csv(E'select * from t', '/tmp/t');`. Using PostgreSQL v10 at UBUNTU 16 LTS.

But this function is working fine:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION test1() RETURNS void AS $f$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'HELLO!!!';
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

---

PS: the `quote_ident()` overload also working fine, was implemented  with

```
CREATE FUNCTION quote_ident(text[]) RETURNS text[] AS $f$
  SELECT array_agg(quote_ident(x)) FROM unnest($1) t(x)
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function is `STRICT` and one of the arguments is `NULL`, the function body is not executed and the result is `NULL`. Remove `STRICT` from the function definition.

Btw, you've mistaken the order of arguments.

Comment: Hi, thanks!  Well, I had never read this [part of the guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.64.6) ;-)   *"RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT or STRICT indicates that the function always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null. If this parameter is specified, the function is not executed when there are null arguments; instead a null result is assumed automatically"*... seems very strange, not make sense to exist "valid STRICT" in a function with NULL defaults.. Is a **PostgreSQL-paser-bug** to not say someting as a warning or error message.

Comment: Note that `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` is the default behaviour. The option `SCTRICT` is very useful in avoiding superfluous calculations on null values. A warning is not a good idea, think about a function executed a few millions times on a larger table.

Comment: "... is very useful in avoiding superfluous calculations on null values  ...", now make sense (!), thanks.